# File access denied?

Tags: java

So I have this JFileChooser:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Navigate into the folder you would like to use for this application's files.");
final JFileChooser fcs = new JFileChooser();
int responses = fcs.showOpenDialog(fcs);
if (responses == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
    dir = fcs.getCurrentDirectory().toString();
}else{
    System.exit(1);
}
```

and when I try to write to dir it says

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: *Insert path here* (Access is denied)
```

And it does that no matter what directory I use, even if it's something like documents or desktop. All I'm trying to do is make a file called maze.txt, and even if I don't use a file chooser and give it a directory in the code it gives me the same error. What's happening? It worked and stopped working all of the sudden after I used mkdir(); In another program...

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Is this perchance an applet?